# Count on Aggregate result starts as zero

Tags: apex

Requirement is to identify the number of records assigned for a given user per day and if it reaches the limit, record has to assign to next user in the queue(All the queueing logic comes from custom objects).

For example let's say John Doe has to get 15 records for a given combination then system has to assign 16th record to next user in the queue.

As you see in the code I am using Aggregate Result to get the count of the record for a given OwnerID and since the count index starts from 0 the system is assigning  only 17th record to next user. That is because the If condition I am having checks for currentWL <= wlScore  is evaluating as 16 <= 15 it goes to the next user for assignment. But by the time John Doe already got 16 records(0-15). How can I avoid this and have the count to start from 1?

```
//Check for user workload
public static String getOwnerAvailability(Distribution_Team_Member__c dtm,List<InquiryInfo>recInfos,Decimal ruleScore){
    String IsUserAvailable;        

    if(dtm.Suspend_from_date__c != null && dtm.Suspend_to_date__c != null){
        IsUserAvailable = 'Not Available';
    }
    try {
        List<AggregateResult> currentLoad = [SELECT Count(Id) recCount FROM Inquiry__c WHERE Category__c =: recInfos[0].category AND
                                                Sub_Category__c =: recInfos[0].subCategory AND Action__c =: recInfos[0].action AND
                                                OwnerId =: dtm.User__c AND LastModifiedDate = TODAY];
        for(AggregateResult ar : currentLoad){
            currentWL = (Integer)ar.get('recCount');
        }
        userMaxCapacity = dtm.Max_Capacity__c;
        wlScore = userMaxCapacity/ruleScore;
        if(currentWL <= wlScore){
            IsUserAvailable = 'Available';
        }
        else{
            IsUserAvailable = 'Unavailable';
        }            
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logError('PDS_InquiryAssignmentController', 'getOwnerAvailability',recInfos[0].recId, ex,null);
    }

    return IsUserAvailable;
}
```

This code gets executed through process builder when user changes the record on Inquiry custom object. So the very first time it executes the SOQL to identify whether user has any records matching to the crieteria it returns as 0.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count will start from `1` only. That means, it will show correct count of number of Ids. You need `<` instead of `<=`.

```
if(currentWL < wlScore){
```

**ADDED:**

You are seeing `0` in log because there are no records matching your conditions in query. Count(Id) does not start from `0`, It just gives exact number of records and 0 if no records are there (matching conditions). And may be later when the conditions are matching, you are getting number of records. The expression `currentWL <= wlScore` is faulty and you need to change it as above `currentWL < wlScore`.

Comment: I had updated my question with screen shot.

Comment: I agree and its a faulty check. I modified and tested and its working good. Thanks for the insight.